# How can I disable values in drop down lists based on user selection using JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

The application have five drop down lists with the same content, but the user cannot select the same content twice.

It could be done by server side validation, but I would like to know if there is a possibility of: When the user select an option in one drop down list it got hidden (do not appear) in the others.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please change your title ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you please post the code you're working on? Then somebody can help to improve it.

Comment: You always need to do serverside validation anyways. Btw, you could just use a  `<select multiple>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("select.xx").change(function() {
                    $("select.xx option").show();

                    $("select.xx").each(function() {
                        if (!$(this).val() == "") {
                            $("select.xx").not($(this)).find("option").filter("[value='" + $(this).val() + "']").hide();
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select class="xx">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
        </select>

        <select class="xx">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
        </select>

        <select class="xx">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
        </select>

        <select class="xx">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
        </select>

        <select class="xx">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
        </select>

    </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: @user2564377: you must accept this answer.

Comment: I know this is solved long time now, but it isn't working on the Internet Explorer (version 10) any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will work

```
var rowHide = document.getElementById('rowid');
rowHide.style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you,

```
$('#select1').on('change',function(){
    $('#select2 option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"').remove();
    // remove the matched value from other drop down box
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example solution here that you might find useful [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gW3C/)

which uses this code:

```
$('.select').change(function(){
   $('.'+$(this).val()).attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

When a select is changed it disabled the corresponding values across all other selects. Assuming the class's on elements are setup like in jsfiddle example

Comment: What if the person decide to change back to other value? The initial chosen value continue disable. How could I re-able the value?

Comment: you should be able to use something like
    `$('.select').change(function(e){
        // reenable previous select
        $('.'+$(e.target).data('pre')).attr("disabled", "enabled");
        // disable new select
        $('.'+$(this).val()).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        // update prevouse select
        $(e.target).data('pre',$(this).val());    
    });`

Comment: sorry replace above .attr("disabled", "enabled"); with .removeAttr('disabled');

Comment: just updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gW3C/2/) to give you a better example